# physics equation in python

Tags: python, equation

I want to make a program that can calculate physics equation where the user enters different parameters: I know its simple like:

```
v=5
t=7
s=v*t
print(s)
```

its only calculating `s = v*t`; however, when I want the equation of `v` if show me an error. Hard coding `v = s/t` gives me the correct result:

```
s=5
t=7
v=s/t
print(v)
```

I want an equation that can solve with different user input; that is if user inputs the `v` and `t` , the equation will return `s = v*t` and if the user inputs `s` and `t` the equation will return `v = s/v`.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do? . It would be great if you mention required outputs and the inputs for the same

Comment: What is the error message that you get? Also you will want to make sure your variables are floats.

Comment: So you basically want to solve for any of the three variables, given the other two variables, with one equation. That (usually) won't work, certainly not in Python. Tools/languages like Mathematica, which use (or accept/interpret) more symbolic input & equations, may be able to do this, but not in a programming language like Python.

Comment: i want an equation that can solve by user input.means that if user inputs the number of v and t , the equation will s = v*t and if the user inputs the number of s and t the equation will be v = s/v

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use key word arguments:

```
def solve_equation(v=None, t=None, s=None):
    if v is not None and t is not None:
        return v * t   # s case
    elif s is not None and t:  # t not None and not 0            
        return s / t   # v case
    else:
        raise ValueError   #"t should be defined or not zero"


print(solve_equation(v=10, t=2))
print(solve_equation(s=2, t=7))
```

#### Output:

```
20
0.2857142857142857
```

Note that if you are using python 2, floats must be passed.

Comment: Re the "floats must be passed" comment, you could bake that into the function if you just change the calculations to be something like `return 1.0 * s / t`. No need to insist user takes care of this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @paxdiablo, it is likely the OP uses python 3, this is why I left it as a remark.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you could define three separate functions, one for each variable. For example,

```
def s(v, t):
    return v*t

def v(s, t):
    return s/t

def t(s, v):
    return s/v
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the zero acceleration "svt" equations (or even the constant acceleration "suvat" ones, should you have more complex requirements), it's a simple matter of detecting  what's unknown, and then filling in the gaps.

The following code provides a function that will do this along with some test code so you can see it in action:

```
# Returns a 3-tuple containing [displacement(s), velocity(v), time(t)],
#    based on the existence of at least two of those.
# If all three are given, the displacement is adjusted so that the
#    equation 's = vt' is correct.

def fillInSvt(s = None, v = None, t = None):
    # Count the unknowns, two or more means no unique solution.

    noneCount = sum(x is None for x in [s, v, t])
    if noneCount > 1: return [None, None, None]

    # Solve for single unknown (or adjust s if none).

    if noneCount == 0 or s is None: return [v*t, v, t]
    if v is None: return [s, s/t, t]
    return [s, v, s/v]

# Test code.

print(fillInSvt(99,4,6))         # Show case that adjusts s.

print(fillInSvt(None,4,6))       # Show cases that fill in unknown.
print(fillInSvt(24,None,6))
print(fillInSvt(24,4,None))

print(fillInSvt(24,None,None))   # Show "not enough info" cases.
print(fillInSvt(None,4,None))
print(fillInSvt(None,None,6))
print(fillInSvt(None,None,None))
```

The output shows that the tuple is filled in in all cases where there's a unique solution:

```
[24, 4, 6]
[24, 4, 6]
[24, 4.0, 6]
[24, 4, 6.0]
[None, None, None]
[None, None, None]
[None, None, None]
[None, None, None]
```

Comment: got it bro , but i am looking for a simple solution . but i think python cant do that simply , i have to hard code alot . anyways thanks..

Comment: @JohnnyDoe, no, Python does not have an inbuilt "SolveSuvat" function. That's why you have to write a small function for it, after which your code *does* have such a beast :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def h2(v,d,t):
    title_ar = 'السرعة'
    title_en = 'speed'
    if v=='':
        print("v= ","%.2f"% (d/t),"m/s")
    elif d=='':
        print("d= ","%.2f"% (v*t),"m")
    elif t=='':
        print("t= ","%.2f"% (d/v),"s")
    else:
        print("please write all data.")

h2('', 2,6)
h2(70,'',8)
h2(25,3,'')
```